# Does a PHP Header(Location:) redirect need to point to a website starting with "http://"?

Tags: php, html, redirect, form-submit, contact-form

I'm doing a bit of web development for a client of mine, and I've run into a roadblock.

**Here's what's going on: **

-We have multiple copies of the same contact form on our website, but we want each to redirect to a different landing page upon completion in order to track conversion rates.

-In this example, I'm working on the about page. When a user submits their request for more information, the page would ideally redirect to a unique Thank-You page (e.g., www.sample.com/thank-you-about.html); however, it's not.

-The email will get sent off perfectly, but the redirection will never take place. No errors are thrown - nothing.

**BEFORE I show the code,** here's what I've tried in order to solve it on my own:

-I've created a body of HTML code underneath the .php code that the form sends its input to. To my knowledge, no redirect is taking place, so I've obviously not seen it yet.

-I've used the call "Header(Location:www.sample.com/thank-you-about.html)", but that's not doing anything either.

-I've tried using Javascript's "frame.location" method, and it doesn't seem to get any further than the php attempt.

-I've saved the source page and destination page as .php pages on the off-chance that using an .html extension is at the root of the problem; same outcome.

Really, the only thing left that I can think of is the connection type not satisfying the requirements for a Header() call. But wouldn't that output an error message?

Here's the contact form in question:

```
 <form id="contactForm" class="get-in-touch contact-form light" action="thank-you-about.php" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" id="contact_nonce" name="contact_nonce" value="68592e213c"/><input type="hidden" name="" value="/"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="contact-form-value" value="1"/>
                        <div class="iconic-input">
                            <input class="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*">
                            <i class="icons icon-user-1"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="iconic-input">
                            <input class="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email*">
                            <i class="icons icon-email"></i>
                        </div>
                        <textarea class="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
                        <div class="iconic-button">
                            <input type="reset" value="Clear">
                            <i class="icons icon-cancel-circle-1"></i>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Here's the current .php file, thank-you-about.php:

```
    <?php

// Define some constants
define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "Sample" );
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "writewoodcopy@gmail.com" );
define( "EMAIL_SUBJECT", "New request from site sample webpage" );

// Read the form values
$success = false;
$senderName = isset( $_POST['name'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['name'] ) : "";
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['email'] ) : "";
$message = isset( $_POST['msg'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['msg'] ) : "";
$messageInterests = "";
$subject = "";
$currentURL = isset($_POST['current-URL'])? $_POST['current-URL'] : "";

//Parse checkboxes, include them in message body
$interestArray = $_POST['interest'];
if(!empty($interestArray)){
    $messageInterests .= "INFORMATION OF INTEREST:   ";
    $N = count($interestArray);
    for($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
        $messageInterests .= "\r\n" . $interestArray[$i];
    }
    $subject .= $messageInterests . "\r\n \r\n";
}
else {
    $subject = "GENERAL INQUIRY \r\n \r\n";
}

$subject .= $message;
$message = $subject;

// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && EMAIL_SUBJECT && $message ) {
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
  $headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">";
  mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $message, $headers );
  header("Location: www.sample.com/thank-you-about.html"); /* Redirect browser */

}

?>
```

**EDIT::** Before anyone asks, I know that no checkboxes are being parsed from this particular contact form. They come in handy on my client's service pages, while general inquiries are handled by the about page, contact us page, and homepage.

**SECOND EDIT::** So, I fixed the absolute URL problem; however, the redirect problem is still persisting. Thank you all for being so patient!

Comment: No better place to start than the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Without `http://`, it is treated as a relative URL, so would be looking for something like `http://example.com/www.sample.com/thank-you-about.html`

Comment: In that case, if the relative URL wasn't found, wouldn't it output an error or at least redirect to a 404 page?

Comment: Check your browser's console. It might be trying to forward to an invalid URL

Comment: You should also add `exit;` after each header. Otherwise, if you have more code below it, it may want to continue to execute.

Comment: Technically, I believe the HTTP spec requires full absolute URLs _all the time_ in a `Location` header, all modern browsers will correctly handle relative URLs. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Comment: I suspect that OP is confusing the response of the POST request, with redirecting the page that the form itself appears on.  By any chance, are you using AJAX to submit the form?

Comment: True, you won't get an error from error reporting, however you should have been thrown a **Not Found** *The requested URL /folder/www.sample.com/thank-you-about.html was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.* etc., no? Logs might also provide information.

Comment: @alexw, to my knowledge, we're not using AJAX. There's no reference to it in the page data, but then again, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I haven't seen anything like that come up in the error-log file that's generated by this page. Checking back on them yield little-to-no useful information on this problem, unfortunately :(

Comment: @user3579647 ok thanks for clarifying.  Btw, you might want to read about the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), which I think is what you are trying to implement here.

Comment: Let's summarize here as to what is going on and what you've currently got: A. Your code is reaching the `mail()` function, correct? It's just not rendering the `header()` redirect? B. You've changed the URL path (to be redirected to)? Eg. `http://www.sample.com/thank-you-about.html` *or* `/thank-you-about.html`? C. You're sure *thank-you-about.html* exists?

Comment: @Marcus, Yes, that's correct. Points A, B, and C are spot-on.

Comment: @alexw, I would love to, but my reputation isn't high enough...

Comment: How about a [gitter chat](https://gitter.im/userfrosting/UserFrosting/SO-36973272)?

Comment: How much of the code you published here is actually needed to explain the problem and reproduce the effect?

Answer (score 6):

> Does a PHP Header(Location:) redirect need to point to a website
>   starting with “http://”?

Yes, if you need to redirect to a file on a **different domain**, you'll have to specify the **full absolute URL**, this includes the protocol (`http`, `https`, etc.), based on that, this **doesn't work**:

```
header("Location: www.sample.com/thank-you-about.html");
```

use:

```
header("Location: http://www.sample.com/thank-you-about.html");
```

---

If you need to redirect to a file on the **same domain** you can use a relative path:

```
header("Location: thank-you-about.html"); //thank-you-about.html is located on the same dir as the current script
```

or

```
header("Location: /thank-you-about.html"); //thank-you-about.html is located on the root dir of the domain
```

---

> `header()` is used to send a raw HTTP header. See the » [HTTP/1.1
>   specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616) for more information on HTTP headers.

Read more about the `php` [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

Comment: I think the question is more of a *"why"* rather than providing a fix.

Comment: Go over the entire question again. You will find *"I've tried using Javascript's "frame.location" method, and it doesn't seem to get any further than the php attempt.

-I've saved the source page and destination page as .php pages on the off-chance that using an .html extension is at the root of the problem; same outcome."* - So there's something deeper at play here.

Comment: The `header()` call takes place within the .php file the form is posting to, if that makes sense. This is my first rodeo with this kind of coding, so I don't blame you for being confused with my methods. ;)

Comment: I doubt it. They state *"Here's the current .php file, thank-you-about.php:"*

Comment: The OP needs to be more clear about the problem, to my knowledge, the error was in `header("Location: www.sample.com/thank-you-about.html");` but I guess I'm wrong...

Comment: Thank you for your help, Pedro - I did have an unresolved problem with static URLs, but the original problem of not redirecting to the landing page is still persisting. Are there any other suggestions you may have?

Comment: You're welcome, but I cannot help your further until I fully understand what your problem is, which I don't.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to pass the redirect parameter as part of the action attribute, i.e

```
     ...action="sendEmail.php?redirect=thank-you-about" method="post">
```

Then read it out server side and redirect accordingly.

```
 // do your sending email logic here, then redirect:
 $r = $_GET['redirect];
 switch($r){
   case: 'thank-you-about':
     header("Location: /thank-you-about.html"); die();
     // it might be tempting to go 'header("Location: /$r")' directly, but this would introduce quite a security vulnerability.

   break;

   case: 'otherpage':
    header("Location: /thank-you-other.html"); die();
   break;

   default:
      header("Location: /thank-you-default.html"); die();
   break;
  }
```

Comment: `$_POST['redirect']` doesn't exist. You're looking for `$r = $_GET['redirect];`

Comment: Ah true that. my bad.

Comment: Hey @RidIculous , thanks for your submission. That's an awesome idea, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same problem. I'll definitely implement that once this is over with!

Comment: if you get a blank page, did you turn on: error_reporting(E_ALL)?